# How to utilize the locateOnScreen function from the PyAutoGUI library on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, animation, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I attempted to execute the following script:

```
import pyautogui
res = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('edit')
print(res)
```

However, I encountered the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/adigweleo/gui2.py", line 2, in 
> res = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('edit')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 172, in wrapper
> return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
> return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/**init**.py", line 375, in locateOnScreen
> screenshotIm = screenshot(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/**init**.py", line 527, in *screenshot_osx
> if tuple(PIL__version*_) < (6, 2, 1):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

I stored the desired screen image as edit in the `Users/adigweleo` directory. Following this, I created and activated a new virtual environment. Subsequently, I employed both `pip` and `pip3` to install Pillow, pyautogui, and pyscreeze. Regrettably, despite these efforts, the issue persists, as indicated in the error message displayed above.

Comment: looks like pillow is outdated, you sure pip is downloading the right version?

Comment: I have the 10.1.0 pillow version

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion: the `locateOnScreen()` function doesn't do OCR or recognize text, so you wouldn't want to pass it the string `'edit'`. Rather, you want to pass it a string of an image filename, and it locates the image on the screen. This image should be from a screenshot you've taken of the thing you want to click on, and must be a pixel-perfect match.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of looking around the pyscreeze library, and i've concluded that the version is wrong.
If you look on the [github](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze), you can see
`if PILLOW_VERSION < (6, 2, 1):` on the line that is erroring.
Except, if you look in your own traceback, the line says `if tuple(PIL__version_) < (6, 2, 1):`  instead. This causes a TypeError, as `PIL__version__` is a string.
Turns out, pull request [99](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/pull/99) on the github has already been put into place and fixed it.
Updating pyscreeze should do the trick.

Comment: I updated pyscreeze with this command 'pip3 install --upgrade pyscreeze' and I still have the same error. I currently use pyscreeze version 0.1.29

Comment: noted. try uninstalling pyscreeze, and then installing from the git repo instead (search how to install from git repo with pip)

Comment: I used this command to clone pyscreeze repo 'git clone https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze.git' , yet the error still exists

Comment: did you also install the downloaded repo with a command, or did you only run git clone?

Comment: I just ran the git clone

Comment: I downloaded the repo from GitHub. Then, I installed pyscreeze using pip3 with the following command: 'pip3 install -e /Users/adigweleo/pyscreeze'.
After the installation, I ran some code. However, I encountered a different error: 'pyautogui.PyAutoGUIException: PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call.'